# Javascript RegExpression, missing charcters

Tags: javascript, jquery, regex

I have a dialogbox within which I try to apply a regular expression, I cant seem to get the right one.

**Structure**

```
ID          151010  This could be of any length
PartDescr   xyz     This could be of any lenhth
Types       1,2,3,4 These are the index of selection from a listbox, n number and  optional
Comment     xyz     This could be of any lenth and optional
SN          xyz     optional text any length
RC          1       optional drop down index value, only one value
```

**Sample Data**

```
151010 ~ Pipettor Aspiration Dispense-Sample Fluidics-Cable/Connections ~ 1,2,3,4 ~ SDSZF ~ S ~ 2 |  151020 ~ Pipettor Aspiration Dispense-Sample Fluidics-Complete Syringe Pump Assy ~ null ~  ~  ~ 1
```

**Intended Data**

```
Pipettor Aspiration Dispense-Sample Fluidics-Cable/Connections ~ 1,2,3,4 ~ SDSZF ~ S ~ 2 |
Pipettor Aspiration Dispense-Sample Fluidics-Complete Syringe Pump Assy ~ null ~  ~  ~ 1
```

As you can see above I am simply trying to get rid of the ID at the start for each part, there could be N number of part selections. Above there are two, It could be one, it could be 2 and so on. My following regex statement works fine in removing the ID but I have noticed that for service types, If I had selected the first 4 selection for example 1,2,3,4, after the regex transformation, I get 1,2,3.  So this is where I need help.  Thanks

```
partTextAreaNoId = x.replace(/\d+\s~\s/g, "");
```

Comment: Of course it does. `4 ~ ` matches your regex.

Comment: Dont overcomplicate your thing with a single replace. Just do a 2 levels split.

Comment: @tam i think your expected contains only one line.

Answer (score 0):

You could try something like:

```
[^,]\d+\s~\s
```

Which would exclude your `,4 ~` substring.

Or alternatively, you could try:

```
(^|\|\s+)\d+\s~\s
```

This will check that your match starts with at the beginning of the string, or is proceeded by `|` plus some number of spaces.

Answer (score 0):

It would be simpler to set your variable to the result of a split excluding the first part(s) (depending on how you split):

```
//Where str has been set to the data
str = str.split('|'), result = [], split = null;
for (var i = 0; i < str.length; i++) {
  split = str[i].split('~');
  result.push('~'.join(split[1,split.length - 1]));
}
```

or

```
//Where str has been set to the data
str = str.split('|'), result = [], split = null;
for (var i = 0; i < str.length; i++) {
  split = str[i].split(' ');
  result.push(' '.join(split[2,split.length - 1]));
}
```

Answer (score 0):

No regex needed, just a little split, indexOf and substring - (UPDATED) http://jsfiddle.net/q84vtfa5/1/

```
var myData = '151010 ~ Pipettor Aspiration Dispense-Sample Fluidics-Cable/Connections ~ 1,2,3,4 ~ SDSZF ~ S ~ 2 |  151020 ~ Pipettor Aspiration Dispense-Sample Fluidics-Complete Syringe Pump Assy ~ null ~  ~  ~ 1';
var arrayData = myData.split('|');
for(i = 0; i < arrayData.length; i++) {
    var idStripped = arrayData[i].substring(arrayData[i].indexOf('~') + 2);
    console.log(idStripped);
}
```

This starts the substring at the first tilde's location, plus two more so that what is left begins with your product's description.

Comment: But there is 2 ids that need to be removed

Answer (score 0):

I think you want something like this,

```
> "151010 ~ Pipettor Aspiration Dispense-Sample Fluidics-Cable/Connections ~ 1,2,3,4 ~ SDSZF ~ S ~ 2 |  151020 ~ Pipettor Aspiration Dispense-Sample Fluidics-Complete Syringe Pump Assy ~ null ~  ~  ~ 1".replace(/((?!,)(?:^|.))\s*\d+\s~\s/g, "$1");
'Pipettor Aspiration Dispense-Sample Fluidics-Cable/Connections ~ 1,2,3,4 ~ SDSZF ~ S ~ 2 |Pipettor Aspiration Dispense-Sample Fluidics-Complete Syringe Pump Assy ~ null ~  ~  ~ 1'
```

**UPDATE:**

```
> "151010 ~ Pipettor Aspiration Dispense-Sample Fluidics-Cable/Connections ~ 1,2,3,4 ~ SDSZF ~ S ~ 2 |  151020 ~ Pipettor Aspiration Dispense-Sample Fluidics-Complete Syringe Pump Assy ~ null ~  ~  ~ 1".replace(/\s*\d+\s~\s(?![^~]*~[^~]*~[^~]*(?:\||$))/g, "");
'Pipettor Aspiration Dispense-Sample Fluidics-Cable/Connections ~ 1,2,3,4 ~ SDSZF ~ S ~ 2 |Pipettor Aspiration Dispense-Sample Fluidics-Complete Syringe Pump Assy ~ null ~  ~  ~ 1'
```

Comment: well this work but lets say if I had selected the service type at index 12, it shows up as 1

Comment: @tamtam this updated solution will work in all the cases only if there are equal number of `~` symbols. I noticed that all the above individual segments contains 5 `~` symbols. I hope there must be 5 `~` for all the segements... :-)

Comment: Your updated solution is working fine, I noticed in some of my selections it removed the tilda. in this case in the second selection the PartDescr ends in R1 so the regx got confused  Wash Cups-Sample ~ 3,4,5,6 ~ sd ~ ~ 1
Wash Cups-R1,2,3,4,5,6 ~ xz ~ ~ 1

Answer (score 0):

Try this on for size:

```
x.replace(/(^|\|\s+)\d+\s+~\s+/g, "$1");
```

Since your regular expression just needs more context - I clued it in that the pipe character was your record separator, and replaced out the first number, tildes, and white space from the record.

When used on:

```
"151010 ~ Pipettor Aspiration Dispense-Sample Fluidics-Cable/Connections ~ 1,2,3,4 ~ SDSZF ~ S ~ 2 |  151020 ~ Pipettor Aspiration Dispense-Sample Fluidics-Complete Syringe Pump Assy ~ null ~  ~  ~ 1"
```

This returns:

```
"Pipettor Aspiration Dispense-Sample Fluidics-Cable/Connections ~ 1,2,3,4 ~ SDSZF ~ S ~ 2 |  Pipettor Aspiration Dispense-Sample Fluidics-Complete Syringe Pump Assy ~ null ~  ~  ~ 1"
```

Comment: After having three selections I am getting the ID in the first selection, rest of it is fine. This is after using your regex transformation 289150 ~ BSM-Piercing Probe Assy ~ 1,2,3,4 ~ ds ~ ds ~ 2. 
BSM-Cubitainer ~ 1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12 ~ ~ ~ 1
BSM-Cubitainer Straw Assy ~ 11,12 ~ ~ ~ 1      There could be N number of selections and in this case there were 3

Answer (score 0):

U can use this regular expression:

```
^\d+\s~\s([\w\d\s-\/]+)\s~\s((?:\d,?)*)\s~\s([\w\d\s-\/]+)?\s~\s([\w\d\s-\/]+)?\s~\s(\d*)
```

Here a bit of the javascript code u can use:

```
var re = /^\d+\s~\s([\w\d\s-\/]+)\s~\s((?:\d,?)*)\s~\s([\w\d\s-\/]+)?\s~\s([\w\d\s-\/]+)?\s~\s(\d*)/; 
var str = '151010 ~ Pipettor Aspiration Dispense-Sample Fluidics-Cable/Connections ~ 1,2,3,4 ~ SDSZF ~ S ~ 2';
var m;

while ((m = re.exec(str)) != null) {
    if (m.index === re.lastIndex) {
        re.lastIndex++;
    }
}
```

And if u want to view your result, or capturing groups, u can use the m-variable like `m[0]` is the first captured group which is `PartDescr`, and `m[1]` is for `Types`, and so on.
Just tell me if u want a detailed explanation of every bit used in the regular expression, I'll pleased to help.

Hope it useful!